# Can I use CSS to affix a div to the top or bottom of a container, depending on whether the div overflows?

Tags: css

I have a restricted space of height x. Within this I have a div of unknown and variable height (Z). If possible, I want to set it to start at position Y (top:Y), but if the height goes below the bottom, then I want to set it to fix the bottom and extend upwards (bottom:0; max-height:X).

[image]

Is there a pure CSS way of achieving this, or do I have to go the JS route?

Comment: I think there isn’t a pure css way, even though there might be a genius and perhaps somewhat convoluted way to do it without JS. My intuition tells me that JS offers a direct and easy solution because it supports conditionals (CSS does, such as media queries, but not in a way that is useful for this scenario).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is what I've been trying: https://jsfiddle.net/4oejjLxe/ (where I want the "inner" div to start at 400px if it's less than 100px in height (i.e. doesn't overlap the end of the yellow block))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but using `flex` with a spacer element should do the trick. The solution is CSS-only and [works in all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

The key (and somewhat of a downside) is to add an empty spacer element to the markup to create the top offset, like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    A short bit of text.
  </div>
</div>
```

And then set the `.container` to

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

so the `.spacer` and `.inner` stack vertically. Finally, add the following CSS to the `.spacer` element:

```
flex: 1;
max-height: 150px; // The amount of offset you want from the top
```

where the `max-height` value is the spacing you want from the top.

Here it is in action:

```css
/* .boxes is only for demo purposes */
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #222222;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      A short bit of text.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      A medium amount of text to fill a few more rows.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      A really, really, really, really, really, really really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really long amount of text to fill the entire height of the element so it forces the inner box to move up.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what `position: sticky` is supposed to solve? Something like this:

```
.outer {
  height: 300px;  /* X */
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 300px;  /* X */
  overflow: auto;
  top: 30px;  /* Y */
}
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/sawox4pa/

It doesn't work on Edge/IE (http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) but you can polyfill it for those browsers: https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill